# Is node terminal frozen or ddosed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was working on long polling chat using node js. I might be wrong, but there was no issue in server side or client side code. I'll leave them at the end of question for those who are interested in reviewing it

Main problem is that node terminal is apparently "freezing".
I load page dynamically sending a request to the server. Usually it takes half a second to load the page

[page loaded in 537ms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhWbD.png)

Then I tried running it on another browser, sent several GET and POST requests and then tried to reload the page one more time. It stucked until I focused on the node terminal window

[the same page loaded in 1.5 min](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88Oyv.png)

The questions are

- is it related to terminal window issues or node itself?
- if so, how I can prevent it?

Browser is chrome, node v16.13.1, os Windows 10

code files:

main.js:

```js
const http = require("http")
const { connection, sendMessage } = require("./chatfunctions")
const { sendFile } = require("./sendFile")

const ip = "127.0.0.1"
const port = 1337

let server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

    console.log("request to", req.url)

    switch (req.url) {

        case "/chat":
            res.setHeader("Content-type", "text/html")
            sendFile("./chat/index.html", res)
            break;
        
        case "/connection":
            //connection
            connection(req, res)
            break;

        case "/message":
            sendMessage(req, res)
            //message
            break;
        
        default:
            res.statusCode = 404
            res.end("Not found")
            //404
            break;
    }

}).listen(port, ip)
```

chatfunctions.js:

```js
let clients = []


function connection(req, res) {


    clients.push(res)

    console.log("new connection", clients.length)


    res.on("close", function() {

        clients.splice(clients.indexOf(res), 1)

        console.log("connection closed", clients.length)
        
    })

}


function sendMessage(req, res) {

    clients.forEach(function(client) {

        req.pipe(client)


        req.on("error", function(err) {

            console.error(err)

            client.status = 500
            client.end("Server error")

        })

        client.on("finish", function() {
            res.end("")
        })

    })

    clients = []

}

exports.connection  = connection;
exports.sendMessage = sendMessage;
```

sendFile.js

```js
const fs = require("fs");

function sendFile(path, res) {

    let fileStream = new fs.ReadStream(path);

    fileStream.pipe(res);


    fileStream.on("error", function (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status = 500;
        res.end("Server error");
    });


    res.on("close", function () {
        fileStream.destroy();
    });
    
}
exports.sendFile = sendFile;
```

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        #form {
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #submit {
            width: 80px;
            height: 30px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 3px;
        }

        #message {
            width: 200px;
            height: 23px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form">
        <input type="text" name="message" id="message">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <script>
        function poll() {

            console.log("creating connection")

            let connection = new XMLHttpRequest()

            connection.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:1337/connection")

            connection.send()


            connection.onload = function () {

                let li = document.createElement("li")

                li.textContent = connection.responseText


                messages.appendChild(li)

                poll()
            }
        }


        form.onsubmit = function (event) {

            event.preventDefault()


            let text = message.value


            let request = new XMLHttpRequest()

            request.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:1337/message")

            request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/plain")

            request.send(text)

        }

        poll()
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: "*It stucked until I focused on the node terminal window*" - that's *very* unusual. Is your terminal process sent to sleep when it's not in focus? Did you disable output buffering so that it blocks the nodejs process until it can print again? This shouldn't happen on a normal system

Comment: @Bergi, no, I used streams everywhere exept a few logs, but seemingly they are not the cause, it stucks even if I removed them

Comment: Node version 16.13.1, browser Chrome, os Windows 10 x64